# Ubuntu 17.10 won't accept correct password

Tags: 17.10

I have been using Artful for a month and nothing like this has happened before. All of a sudden my (correct) login password won't get accepted. The login screen reappears after having turned to black. I have tried resetting my password via grub, but when I try logging in the same thing happens; the new password won't be accepted and after a moment or two I am prompted to log in again. I read on a website removing some of the installed kernels might help. Is this true? What exacly is wrong with my system here?

P.S. I don't have an Xauthority file.

@janasaiarun I ran the  df  -hl command and this is the output:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GKGq.jpg)

Comment: Try wrong credentials. Same result?

Comment: login with virtual consoles. Ctrl+Alt+F1.  enter your username and password

Comment: I agree with @janasaiarun. It's possibly not an unaccepted password (which will cause an error message telling you you entered an incorrect password), but could be your /home directory is full and temporary files needed by gui can't be created (which is detected, then login fails and you are returned to login screen without any message). Alternative conditions (permissions etc) are possible to, but they'd because you installed or changed something; running out of disk space is easily overlooked until login fails. Login using term and do a `df -hl`  to check you have space available.

Comment: @guiverc i guess his gui is corrupted. thats what happen to me a lot of times.

Comment: I had once the bug that my keyboard layout was not used but the american qwerty was used instead. So I had to learn to type my password from an american layout although mine wasn't, in order to log in and then fix the bug.

Comment: janasairaium if gui is corrupted, how do you fix it?

Comment: Can someone just tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @Gregor have u tried by login into virtual console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1(for laptops you need to press Fn button as well). if yes, try guiverc comment i.e., df -hl and edit your question with the output you got.

Answer (score 0):

If keyboard is a problem, you can try Onscreen keyboard. 
You can also change keyboard layout, by clicking the upper bar icon.